# Magento 2 : How to Debug Which Extension is Causing Early Session Timeout or Logout of Admin

Tags: magento2, admin, session, logout

I have a problem in admin section where I frequently get logged out at random intervals of time.

One thing that I am assured is that one of my extension is causing trouble but I could not find way to debug which extension does that.

I referred **Alan storm's** article on **early session timeout** which was quite helpful, but still could not figure out any solution to this problem.

So basically, is there a way to debug this case.